# Is there a way to match one cell to multiple cells in a second sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to calculate order price for a Pizza Place.

I have item prices in one sheet:

[image]

And Order number in the other:
[image]

I want to match the order number in the two sheets and add the values of price if the order ID is the same in the two sheets.

I have been trying using VLOOKUP to match the values but the match runs only once for the two cells and adds the price of the next cell.

[image]

The order table contains the id and the dates and the order_detail table contains the items in the order and their prices.

Here's the Formula i've tried:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,order_details!A1:$D$48621,2,FALSE), 
VLOOKUP(order_details!$C:$C,Table1[#All],4,FALSE) * order_details!$D:$D)
```

I looked up the first value in the first two tables with:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,order_details!A1:$D$48621,2,FALSE)
```

Then for the calculation expression I looked up the price in the other table to match the pizza_id in the order table and the pizza_id in the lookup table and return the price and multiplied it with the quantity column in the order table:

```
=VLOOKUP(order_details!$C:$C,Table1[#All],4,FALSE) * order_details!$D:$D
```

I simplified this by creating a new column to house item prices in the order details.

Is there an easier way to solve this problem in Power BI? if yes then please share the measure or the column I need to make I have created the relations but I couldn't proceed further so I moved back to Excel.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((order_details!$B$2:$B$48621=A2)*(order_details!$E$2:$E$48621)*(order_details!$D$2:$D$48621))`

Comment: Check [SUMIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)